# Printing an array of arrays on one line in console (one line per master array object) in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays that is currently printing each object in the array on its own line. The master array holds many different people inside of it. Each person has 5 different objects stored to them (e.g. Last Name, First Name, DOB.. etc)

```
Kournikova
Anna
F
6/3/1975
Red

Hingis
Martina
F
4/2/1979
Green

Seles
Monica
F
12/2/1973
Black
```

What I'm trying to do is print out each person and their corresponding objects on one line, per person.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Additionally, the output should not contain array brackets (`[]`) or commas. I'm wondering if it will simply need to be a string, or if there is something I am missing.

Some of my code below:

```
space_array = [split_space[0],split_space[1],split_space[3],new_date,split_space[5]]
master << space_array 
puts master
```

The ideal output would be something like this:

```
Kournikova Anna F 6/3/1975 Red
Hingis Martina F 4/2/1979 Green
Seles Monica F 12/2/1973 Black
```

Comment: Please try and use actual text rather than images of text in your post. It is much harder to parse.

Comment: And if the image host goes off line the question becomes useless.

Comment: Edited for the above suggestions.

Comment: After all these years, I'm here to say that I regret ever asking this question because it was part of a take-home coding test, which I was not equipped to answer on my own. The only reason I've decided to keep this up here is that it _has_ helped some people. But for those of you who read this and are trying to pass some test; do better than I did and don't straight up ask large pieces of the test on StackOverflow. If you aren't prepared, spend time getting better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
your_array.each do |person|
  puts person.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: what if array contains only numbers. if your_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]? then how do you print each element on a single line

Answer (score 12):

The method puts will automatically put a new line. Use print instead to print the text out with no new line.

Or if you want, you can use the join function.

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].join(' ') 
=> 'a b c'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate over the outer array and `join` the inner arrays into a string. Since you provide no example data ready for copying and pasting, here's some example code I made up:

```
outer_array.each { |inner| puts inner.join(' ') }
```

Answer (score 0):

more simple:

```
puts your_array.join(" ")
```